# RuboCop complains when using 'Hash.new'

Tags: ruby, rubocop

RuboCop complains when I use `Hash.new`, and suggests that I instead use a hash literal. Is there a way to make RuboCop ignore uses of `Hash.new`? More specifically, can I edit my `.rubocop.yml` configuration to allow the use of `Hash.new` without raising any complaints?

Comment: Why do you want to use Hash.new?

Comment: I'm fairly new to Ruby, but as far as my understanding goes both {} and Hash.new provide the same functionality. I simply choose the more aesthetically pleasing solution if that makes any sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can disable the [`Rubocop::Cop::Style::EmptyLiteral`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/bbatsov/rubocop/Rubocop/Cop/Style/EmptyLiteral) cop within the rubocop.yml file:

```
# .rubocop.yml
Style:
  EmptyLiteral: false
```

Or if you want just to ignore a certain line:

```
hsh = Hash.new # rubocop:disable Style/EmptyLiteral
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [Ruby Style Guide](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide#literal-array-hash) literal array and hash creation notation are preferred unless you need to pass parameters to their constructors. So, to follow the guide you should use `hash = {}` instead `hash = Hash.new`.

I would follow the conventions in the guide, but in case that you do not want, you can disable the [Style/EmptyLiteral cop](https://rubocop.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cops_style/#styleemptyliteral), as for any other cop, either locally or globally.

#### Globally

Add to you `rubocop.yml` file:

```
Style:
  EmptyLiteral: false
```

#### Locally

```
# rubocop:disable Style/EmptyLiteral
hash = Hash.new 
# rubocop:enable Style/EmptyLiteral
```

or the short version for a single line:

```
hash = Hash.new # rubocop:disable Style/EmptyLiteral
```

---

For more information about how to configure Rubocop check [its documentation](https://github.com/bbatsov/rubocop/blob/master/manual/configuration.md).